# Using levenshtein on parts of string in SQL

Tags: sql, levenshtein-distance

I am trying to figure out a way to work some fuzzy searching methods into our store front search field using the Levenshtein method, but I'm running into a problem with how to search for only part of product names.

For example, a customer searches for `scisors`, but we have a product called `electric scissor`. Using the Levenshtein method `levenshtein("scisors","electric scissor")` we will get a result of 11, because the electric part will be counted as a difference.

What I am looking for is a way for it to look at substrings of the product name, so it would compare it to `levenshtein("scisors","electric")` and then also `levenshtein("scisors","scissor")` to see that we can get a result of only 2 in that second substring, and thus show that product as part of their search result.

Non-working example to give you an idea of what I'm after:

```
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE levenshtein("scisors", p.name) < 5
```

**Question:** Is there a way to write an SQL statement that handles checking for parts of the string? Would I need to create more functions in my database to be able to handle it perhaps or modify my existing function, and if so, what would it look like?

I am currently using this implementation of the levenshtein method:

```
//levenshtein(s1 as VARCHAR(255), s2 as VARCHAR(255))
//returns int


  BEGIN
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR;
    -- max strlen=255
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
    IF s1 = s2 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s2_len;
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN
      RETURN s1_len;
    ELSE
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1;
      END WHILE;
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1;
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO
          SET c = c + 1;
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1;
          END IF;
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost;
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF;
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1;
            IF c > c_temp THEN 
              SET c = c_temp; 
            END IF;
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1;
        END WHILE;
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
    RETURN c;
  END
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem, I'm actually looking for exactly the same solution for my database ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

First, I would suggest using a full-text search with a synonyms list.  That said, you might have users with really bad spelling abilities, so the synonyms list might be difficult to maintain.

If you use Levenshtein distance, then I suggest doing it on a *per word* basis.  For each word in the user's input, calculate the closest *word* in the `name` field.  Then add these together to get the best match.

In your example, you would have these comparisons:

- levenshtein('scisors', 'electric')
- levenshtein('scisors', 'scissor')

The minimum would be the second.  If the user types multiple words, such as `'electrk scisors'`, then you would be doing

- levenshtein('electrk', 'electric')  <-- minimum
- levenshtein('electrk', 'scissor')
- levenshtein('scisors', 'electric')
- levenshtein('scisors', 'scissor')  <-- minimum

This is likely to be an intuitive way to approach the search.

Comment: I think you misread the question. You basically just reworded my question and gave it back to me. :) A minor error, in the 2nd example with multiple words you wrote one of the minimum on the wrong row, should be the top of them. But yeah, that's a good consideration on how to handle multiple words as well. At the moment the search is really plain, and it splits the search field on spaces and does a LIKE-search on each word if it can't match anything on the full string as a whole. A synonym list is going to be a bit hard to maintain with thousands of products, but thanks for the suggestion!